# Set hidepid=1 persistently at boot

Tags: linux, mount, fstab, proc

I'd like my system's `/proc` directory to be mounted with the `hidepid=1` option. I know that once the system is already up, I can do that with `sudo mount /proc -o remount,hidepid=1`. How can I make `/proc` just be mounted this way at startup? I'm used to adding filesystem options like this to `/etc/fstab` to do this, but `/proc` doesn't have an entry there. If possible, I'd like for this to happen when `/proc` is first mounted, rather than doing something hacky like remounting it in `/etc/rc.local`.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a custom initrd image. That's where `/proc/` is usually mounted. For example, in the `./init` file from my `/initrd.img`:

> ```
> mount -t sysfs -o nodev,noexec,nosuid sysfs /sys
> mount -t proc -o nodev,noexec,nosuid proc /proc
> ```

You should add your options there, then repack the initrd with mkinitramfs(8).

Also notice that all the options from the kernel's "command line" from `grub`/`lilo` not recognized by the kernel will be passed through to init, so you can scan `"$@"` in `/init` and make the `hidepid` conditional on an argument passed that way.

But I'm not convinced that the `hidepid` option is worth anything.

---

Note: If you're unconvinced that it's `/init` (and not `/sbin/init`, etc) which is run by default in the case where an initrd is used, or if you have trouble unpacking/packing the initramfs image, feel free to ask another question about that ;-)

Answer (score -1):

in order to make users see only their own process (except root can see everything) you need to edit `/etc/fstab`

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults,hidepid=1   0    0
```

Notes:

1. `hidepid=0` (default): This is the default setting and gives you the default behaviour.
2. `hidepid=1`: With this option an normal user would not see other processes but their own about ps, top etc, but he is still able to see process IDs in `/proc`
3. `hidepid=2`: Users are only able too see their own processes (like with hidepid=1), but also the other process IDs are hidden for them in `/proc`

Comment: `defaults` does the wrong thing there. Without this line in my fstab, /proc gets mounted with options `rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime`. With it, it gets mounted as `rw,relatime,hidepid=1`. (I'd hope that there are no files in /proc where any of that would matter, but I'm not 100% sure of that.)

Comment: Hi @JosephSible I have checekd defaults in fstab, according to "https://www.iezzi.ch/process-hiding-hidepid-capabilities-of-procfs/", and "https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-hide-processes-from-other-users/"  it is ok to add `defaults` inside `/etc/fstab`